# How to build an API for a social network like twitter, facebook?

Tags: android, api, rest, laravel

I have some knowledge of Android Development, have done some apps consuming restful, but know I want to develop my own API, I'm developing a social network that is going to work like Facebook, people can post photos, there is gonna be a like button and they can comment, each one will have a profile with pictures, etc.

But I don't know how to build the API, I want to use laravel for that, I found the most practical, clean framework, but I need a guide on how to build that API, what and where should I start?

Comment: @luschn you should not waste your time if you're not going to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many specifics involved in creating an API but here is some information to get you started.

If you are planning to expose your API to be used by third parties(and not just your app) then you will need to put in an authentication method in place. The current specification for that(which facebook, github etc use) is OAUTH2. You can read more about OAUTH2 here https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749

As for implementing it in Laravel, http://oauth2.thephpleague.com/ is a package to get you started but you can google and find a lot more.

If you are planning to use the API internally only by your app then you can implement a much light weight authentication method.

Once the authentication method is in place, it is all a matter of exposing your database data through JSON. This is as simple as querying your database and sending the results as JSON response. Think of this as a normal MVC website, only that the response is not templated HTML, it's JSON.

Also, just like some areas of your website require authentication so you make a check if the user is logged in, in this case, this will be taken care of by the OAUTH2 framework so that all requests to your API are authenticated.

As for the architecture, the servers for OAUTH2, API and the database will be separate. You can also implement load-balancing if you are expecting a high traffic on your API.